# How to resolve Vulnerable Named Pipes security issues in attach surface analyzer report?

Tags: client-side-attacks

I have generated attack-surface-analysis-report. and got one security issue related Vulnerable Named Pipes. and decription was "The ACL on pipe SafeNet-SentinelPIPE-3420-5088 allows tampering by multiple non-administrator accounts."

I have checked in my code for named pipes. I doesn't used any named pipes in my application still i'm getting this security issue on attach surface analyzer report.
I have checkedin services and windows, whether I'm using any named pipes-Safenet or SentinelPipe.

Answer (score 0):

When you get security issue like "Vulnerable Named Pipes".

- First check in code you're using any named pipes, if yes add access perssions to that
- If not, check in control panel for safenet or Sentinel.
- Uninstall the Sentinel from programs and run again attack-surface-analysis.
- This time you dont see any security issues related sentinel.